# How to test if my server is secure?

Tags: penetration-test, webserver

I'm using a debian7 VPS for hosting my websites. I have only installed webmin, apache, mysql, SSH and a wordpress website. I always update my packages and wordpress version.
What is the best (free) user friendly tool to test my server for any possible security weaknesses? Also feel free to give me any tips that i would need to know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. There are OS security scanners, web application scanners, and others. There are many free ones, but they all require skill and understanding to make proper sense of their results.

Comment: Also note that some hosting services do not want people running security scans on their systems. Please check with your hosting provider.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for your answer. Can you please name me some scanners? just the most significant ones, i'd like to work with these tools. I think i can understand results. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are running a VPS you should be able to gain sufficient access, usually via SSH, to configure and install helpful software to automate some of the tasks required.

You should  look at tools such as LSAT and Lynis that support the process of doing a security audit:
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/utils/lsat 
https://cisofy.com/lynis/

You should also spend time studying the OWASP site and running tools like Zed on your domains / IPs:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

All of these tools are free, you might also like to read more about auditing Linux here:
http://linux-audit.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you sir! OWASP seems very interesting. I'll get right on it! :)